# How to write simple Xcode Swift program without a UI

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, output, target

I'm trying to get familiar with Xcode and Swift by writing a simple hello world program that has no UI.

When I create a new empty project in Xcode, there is no Target (scheme?), so I can't build and run.  How can I create a target/scheme to satisfy the minimal build requirements?
Steps to reproduce:

1. Xcode > New > Project > Other > Empty
2. code = print ("TEST")
3. build/run disabled

Alternatively, when I create a new App project it has UI that I can't seem to ignore. Where can I insert a function and print statement without getting a compile time error?
Steps to reproduce:

1. Xcode > New Project > Mac/iOS/TVos/watchOS > App
2. Put a print statement virtually anywhere in any file gives a compiler error

Answer (score 5):

If you just code without UI you can use Playground:

```
Xcode -> File -> New -> Playground
```

Comment: But you can't set breakpoints, etc. in playground. How do you create a C-like swift program in Xcode with a 'main()' that you can run and watch the results in the Console?  No GUI.

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is just writing a simple swift program, then you can create a swift file as simple as below:

test.swift

```
print("hello world")
```

Then run `swift test.swift` in your terminal.

If you want to use Xcode, then you can create a simple command-line app by selection: Xcode -> File -> Project -> mac OS -> Command Line Tool.
Then Xcode will create a project with a swift file call `main.swift` which contains a simple print statement. Just build and run your project and check the console out.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to get familiar with Xcode and Swift by writing a simple hello world program that has no UI.

One way is to create a macOS Command Line Tool:

1. Go to "File" > "New" > "Project", or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.
2. Select "macOS" > "Command Line Tool"

   [image]
3. Enter the details of your project as usual
4. After the project is created, you will see a `main.swift` file. This is your program's entry point. You will see a `print` call already written there for you.

> Alternatively, when I create a new App project it has UI that I can't seem to ignore. Where can I insert a function and print statement without getting a compile time error?

You can do this in the `viewDidLoad` method in the `ViewController.swift` which is automatically generated.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // write your code here:
    print("Hello World!")
}
```

But I would recommend just creating a command line tool, or a playground as aturan23 said if you just want to get familiar with Swift, since they have less distractions.